# I can not call EJB3 from another project

Tags: java, javabeans, ejb-3.0

I'm getting nervous not understanding how the ejb has to be called, since I'm getting errors with a simple example.

I have an EJB project called `Test`. It has only two classes: HelloWorldBean , HelloWorldInterface

```
    //HelloWorldBean 
package com.demo; 
import javax.ejb.Remote; 
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Remote(HelloWorldInterface.class) 
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldInterface {

        public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello world !";
        } 
}

    //HelloWorldInterface  
package com.demo; 
public interface HelloWorldInterface {
            String helloWorld();
        }
```

Both are packed in a WAR called `Test.WAR` that has Test.jar inside, and it is deployed in the WAS 7.0 server.

I have another project called  `TestWeb` that will be packed and deployed in the same server.
Here I implemented a controller of the mvc.

```
package controller;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class My_Controller {

    @EJB
    private HelloWorldInterface helloBean;

    @RequestMapping("testpage")
    public ModelAndView mostraPagina(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("testpage");
        model.addObject("hello", "? " + "EJB:" + helloBean.helloWorld());

        return model;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the errors in the following lines:

- private HelloWorldInterface helloBean;
- model.addObject("hello", "? " + "EJB:" + helloBean.helloWorld());

Edit:
The error is:

```
HelloWorldInterface cannot be resolved to a type. Location: My_Controller.java
```

Comment: What errors are you getting on those lines? Are you sure that you added HelloWorldInterface.class in your classpath?

Comment: I edit the question. The error is: HelloWorldInterface cannot be resolved to a type. Location: My_Controller.java

Comment: How do I have to check the classpath with RAD 8.5? Do I have to go to properties-> build path?

Comment: You have to create a client lib jar from your ejb project. Including the interface. Place this jar in WEB-INF/libs of your web project

Comment: Ok, I going to try this solution. Thank you!

Comment: In realty thinking about it I've understood that this is not a good solution for me, because I'm going to develop a bean that will communicate with the DB and with the Interface. The application that will use the bean has to be separate with it. I mean I can not include the bean as a library.

Comment: When you deploy the ejb project separated from the web project you have a remote conn between both apps. If you combine both in one package you have a locale connection. Best would be when you first learn the basics about deployment and remote verses locale connections.

Comment: The _client library_ should only contain the interface. In this case `HelloWorldInterface`. The project containing the bean and the client then both have a dependency on that interface project, but are independent on each other.

Comment: So I created two projects: Test (with the implementation) and TestClient (with the interfaces) that will be packed in the same EAR. Now how can I include the jar in the third project (the web one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created from the beginning a new ejb project and I chose to generate his client. After that, I create a session bean with the remote interface and I used the RAD option "expose the RPC adapter service" with the Web project. 
In this way I have two EARs both with two jars (including the client).

Roughly speaking:

- First EAR

  - EJB JAR, Client JAR
- Second EAR

  - Web JAR, Client JAR